# Basis of $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ as topological space

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

What is the basis of $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ as topological space?

My try:
The local basis at $a$ is given by {$x∈\Bbb{Q}_p｜｜x-a｜_p＜p^{-n}$, $n∈\Bbb{Z}$・・・①}

① is equivalent to $ord_p(x-a)＞n$・・・②.
But I cannot proceed from here, I thought at first that ② is equivalent to
$x-a∈p^n \Bbb{Q}$. But this is meaningless because $p^n \Bbb{Q}＝\Bbb{Q}$.
So I should have made some mistake. I believe the basis is written like {$a +p^n◾️$}, but I'm having trouble how to find ◾️.

Comment: The ◾️ is $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Could you tell me why ? why ② is equivalent to $x-a∈p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ ?

Comment: Because by definition $\Bbb Z_p =\{x \in \Bbb Q_p: \operatorname{ord}_p(x) \geq 0\}$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot $n$ is integer, and can be negative. I understand, thank you.

Comment: $$\{a+p^n\mathbb Z_p\mid n\in\mathbb Z, a\in\mathbb Q_p\}$$ is this basis

Comment: @Thomas Andrews  I asked this question because I wanted to prove $f:x→1/x$ on $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ is continuous for this topology. Inverse image of ${a +p^n \Bbb{Z}_p)$ by $f$ is exactly $a +p^n \Bbb{Z}_p$ , so continuous?

Comment: Don 't ask an entirely different question in comments. You need $0\not\in a+p^n\mathbb Z_p$ first, then you want $f^{-1}(a+p^n\mathbb Z_p)$ to be a union of sets of the form $a'+p^{n'}\mathbb Z_p,$ not equal. @afortiori

Comment: Technically, you don't need $0\not\in a+p^n\mathbb Z_p,$ but you definitely need that the inverse image is a union of basis elements, and not just the same basis element.

Comment: $a +p^nZ_p$ is not basis, it is local basis at a. Could you tell me what is the inverse of {${(a +p^nZ_p})$｜$a∈\Bbb{Q}$,$n∈\Bbb{Z}$}? I think that is {${(a +p^nZ_p} ｜$a∈\Bbb{Q}$,$n∈\Bbb{Z})$}.

Comment: Maybe being pedantic, but there is no such thing as "*the* basis of $\mathbb Q_p$ as a topological space". Almost all topological spaces, including this one, have many different bases. Same for "local basis".